# Why did javascript NOT throw type error when I try to access a property that does not exist?

Tags: javascript

Why did javascript not throw a type error when I try to access a property that does not exist?

My code is below

```
var array = [];
var someBoolean1 = array[0] && array[0].hey;
```

The value of someBoolean turned out be 'undefinded'; I expect javaScript will throw a type error;

When I do

```
var array = [];
var someBoolean2 = array[0].hey;
```

The typeerror is thrown as expected.

But I do not understand why there is no type error in the first block of code.
Any idea?

Comment: Google for "short-circuit evaluation"

Comment: It is because the second part of the AND is not executed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you explicitly guard against the type error...

```
array[0] && array[0].hey
```

`array[0]` is undefined, so:

```
undefined && array[0].hey
```

`undefined` is *falsey*, so the right hand side is not evaluated, so the result of this expression is the left hand value `undefined`, which is assigned to `someBoolean1`.

---

Tangentially... to make such expressions less repetitive, usually this idiom is used:

```
var someBoolean1 = (array[0] || {}).hey;
```

If `array[0]` is `undefined`, `{}` will be used instead, and then the property `.hey` of that object will be accessed. If `array[0]` is an object with a property `.hey`, you'll get its value, otherwise you'll *safely* get `undefined` out of the entire expression.

Answer (score 2):

No type error is thrown because your and operator is short circuiting, array[0] is undefined, which is not true, meaning javascript doesn't feel the need to check the second part of your and condition, and doesn't realize that there is a type error.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (false && "any another statement is unreachable")  
   then do something;
```

second expression not evaluated  as `array[0]` false `array[0].hey` is not reached

```
var someBoolean1 = array[0] && array[0].hey;
```

Comment: too fast your comment is, changing on the way

Comment: You should thrive to post full answers. Once an answer is posted, it is exposed to the judgement of users.

Comment: Seriously saying this in SO :)

Comment: ... Yes. Stack Overflow is about building a common programming knowledge base, not who's going to fill the text box first.

Comment: Do you ever wonder why there is no edit info for first minutes on answers

Comment: Proofreading time.

Comment: @Kyll So you never did `not who's going to fill the text box first` right?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of the execution of `&&` expression. `array[0]` happend to be evaluated to false so the rest of the expression is not evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**:

Because there is no element at the index `0` of `array`, and in more generic words, the property `0` is not defined in variable `array`. Therefore calling a property on something that is not defined would give you an error.

**Long Answer**:

Consider all JavaScript objects as dictionaries, and lets think that these dictionaries return us the values if we provide the keys that exist in them, otherwise nothing is returned.

Therefore when accessing an object property like `myObject.propA` (which is same as `myObject["propA"]`), if it exists in this object then the value of that property is returned and if not then `undefined` is returned, which denotes that this property is not defined in the `myObject`.

An array (`[]`) in JavaScript is also a type of object, and each member in the array is actually the property of that object. So a property in `var arr = ["asd", "fgh"]` can be accessed by `arr[0]` or `arr["0"]`, which means that if property `0` of `arr` exists then it would return the value (in this case "asd"), otherwise would return undefined.

Providing all this, calling a property on something that is undefined is both illogical and illegal, so an exception is raised.